# Clustering from MVT in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers, clustering, mbtiles

How to write OpenLayers code to create clusters from MVT (using 100k points)?

Because MVT file format saves disk space (90 % less than GeoJSON) and requires only 50 % RAM of browser.

Class hierarchy of mbtiles as vectortile:

> ol.Map / layers: ol.layer.VectorTile / source: ol.source.VectorTile /
>   format: ol.format.MVT

Class hierarchy of GeoJSON as cluster:

> ol.Map / layers: ol.layer.Vector / source: ol.source.Cluster / source:
>   ol.source.Vector / format: ol.format.GeoJSON

Answer (score 1):

MVT as ol.layer.VectorTile should work using [Mapbox supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster).

Depending on your file size you could also go directly with geojson as it is shown in this [Openlayers example](https://webgeodatavore.github.io/supercluster/demo/index-ol.html).